# Apply a "mask" to a string

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string

I have a flag enumeration (int) mask, and I need to convert it to a string representing the day of a Week.

say this is the FULL string and an arbitrary mask

```
strFullWeek = "MTWtFSs"
strWeekMask = "0100110"
-----------------------
strResult   = "-T--FS-"
```

what way would you propose to obtains strResult from full week and mask strings?

## UPDATE

this is my "entire context" (VB.NET)

```vb
<Flags()> Public Enum Week
  Monday = 1
  Tuesday = 2
  Wednesday = 4
  Thursday = 8
  Friday = 16
  Saturday = 32
  Sunday = 64
End Enum

Dim mondayOrSunday = Week.Monday Or Week.Sunday
Dim strDays = "MTWtFSs"

Dim strMondayOrSundayBinary = Convert.ToString(
  mondayOrSunday, 2).PadRight(7, CChar("0"))

Dim charMondayOrSunday = strDays.Zip(
  strMondayOrSundayBinary,
  Function(day, mask) If(mask = CChar("1"), day, CChar("-"))).ToArray()

Dim strMondayOrSunday = New String(charMondayOrSunday)

Console.WriteLine("{0} I see as {1}",
                  mondayOrSunday,
                  strMondayOrSunday)
```

Comment: What are you most concerned about?  Speed, maintainability/readability, least lines of code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a reasonably neat LINQ way:

```
var chars = strFullWeek.Zip(strWeekMask, (day, mask) => mask == '1' ? day : '-'))
                       .ToArray();
string text = new string(chars);
```

It wouldn't be terribly efficient, but it may be good enough...

EDIT: Okay, assuming you're happy with C# code for the enum version

```
// TODO: Rename "Week" to comply with .NET naming conventions
Week mask = Week.Monday | Week.Sunday;
var chars = strFullWeek.Select((value, index) => (int) mask & (1 << index) != 0) 
                                                 ? value : '-')
                       .ToArray();
string text = new string(chars);
```

Comment: To obtain the `strWeekMask` I used `Convert.ToString(myEnum, 2)`... perhaps I could use the enum directly?

Comment: @serhio: Yes, almost certainly. Give us the full context and we'll be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: the full context is simple I have a flag enumeration representing the days of the week, the taks is to transform it to a human readable string ("-T--FS-")

Comment: @serhio: Don't *tell* us the context - *edit the enum into your question*. Show the "raw" information you've got. There may very well be a better way of approaching the problem to start with.

Answer (score 5):

My speedy solution uses a `StringBuilder`. It allows you to manipulate a string in-place. But unless you are calling this code one million times, you won't notice any difference in speed compared to the LINQ solutions.

```
string strFullWeek = "MTWtFSs";
string strWeekMask = "0100110";

var sb = new StringBuilder(strFullWeek);
for (int i = 0; i < strWeekMask.Length; i++) {
    if (strWeekMask[i] == '0') {
        sb[i] = '-';
    }
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
var strFullWeek = "MTWtFSs";
var strWeekMask = "0100110";

var strFullWeekArray = strFullWeek.ToList();
var strWeekMaskArray = strWeekMask.ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(
    string.Empty,
    strFullWeek.Select(c => (strWeekMaskArray[strFullWeekArray.IndexOf(c)] == '1')
        ? c
        : '-')));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative if you're looking for readability:

```
string fullWeek = "MTWtFSs";
string weekMask = "0100110";

const char blankChar = '-';

int totalChars = fullWeek.Length;

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

for (int index = 0; index < totalChars; index++)
{
    if (weekMask[index] == '1')
    {
        result.Append(fullWeek[index]);
    }
    else
    {
        result.Append(blankChar);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party; but I wanted to try.  Here's my less cool LINQ approach:

```
var result = new string(strFullWeek.Select((letter, index) 
                         => strWeekMask[index] == '1' ? letter : '-').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the enumeration directly, you could do so with something like this:

```cs
[Flags()]
enum Week
{
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 8,
    Friday = 16,
    Saturday = 32,
    Sunday = 64
}

const string strFullWeek = "MTWtFSs";

string GetMaskedWeek(Week days)
{
    char[] result = new char[strFullWeek.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strFullWeek.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((((int)days >> i) & 1) != 0)
            result[i] = strFullWeek.ToCharArray(i, 1)[0];
        else
            result[i] = '-';
    }
    return new string(result);
}
```

Or, in VB.NET:

```vb
<Flags()> Public Enum Week
    Monday = 1
    Tuesday = 2
    Wednesday = 4
    Thursday = 8
    Friday = 16
    Saturday = 32
    Sunday = 64
End Enum

Dim strFullWeek As String = "MTWtFSs"

Private Function GetMaskedWeek(ByVal days As Week) As String
    Dim result(strFullWeek.Length) As Char
    For i As Integer = 0 To strFullWeek.Length - 1
        If ((days >> i) And 1) <> 0 Then
            result(i) = strFullWeek.ToCharArray(i, 1)(0)
        Else
            result(i) = "-"c
        End If
    Next
    Return New String(result)
End Function
```

Comment: That's actually what I originally had, but I updated it to match the enum in the question, which has Thursday as 16 :)